# taking voice data in android application from microsoft band

Tags: android, sdk, microphone, microsoft-band

I am trying to develop an android application, where i need to take data from microsoft band's microphone, is it possible to access data voice data from the microphone ?

Answer (score 2):

No, the Band SDK does not expose the Band's microphone to 3rd-party applications.